# Using OCR in Subtitle Edit

Tags: subtitle

I use Subtitle Edit in windows when converting .PGS subs to an .SRT format using the built-in OCR utility in the windows version of Subtitle Edit, but it looks like the Ubuntu version of Subtitle Edit doesn't have that capability... or does it and it requires other elements to be installed to work? Anybody else use Subtitle Edit in Ubuntu (16.04 to 17.10) and know if there's a way to 'turn-on' its OCR function like in windows?

Answer (score 0):

The Subtitle Editor (note that I typed "Editor" and not "Edit" package that is in the Ubuntu repos is not the same program as the Subtitle Edit program that is referred to in threads concerning OCR subtitle conversion.  The program in the Ubuntu repos is not designed to be OCR capable in any respect.  The subtitleedit program that can do OCR requires .NET and Windows, or MONO and the Windows executable.  Hope this helps!